# Discharging a capacitor without a resistor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, capacitance, discharge

Is the following circuit considered un-safe? That is, can a capacitor be discharged with a bare wire connecting the two terminals, or should some resistance be applied? Why or why not?

[image]

Additionally, what are the more common ways used to discharge a capacitor?

Comment: You can use a bare wire. But you should use a resistor so the current isn't as high as it could possibly be. For larger capacitors, just using a bare wire not doing this will make a big spark and a big bright flash and for realllly big capacitors I suppose could weld the wire. When emptying a pressurized tank of air, do you release the air slowly in a controlled manner? Or do you just break off the valve and just let the air pressure explosively release?

Comment: That circuit isn't well defined since it charges the capacitor to infinite voltage. Ignoring that, shorting a capacitor is a bad idea. You may burn out things.

Comment: The terminals will be destroyed by the sparks. Maybe not today, maybe not tomorrow, but soon. [Wikipedia: EDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_discharge_machining).

Comment: As user2850479 says, putting an ideal short circuit in parallel with a charged ideal capacitor results in a nonsense circuit. You can't analyze such a circuit by conventional circuit laws (particularly KVL). In the real world you can connect a real wire across the capacitor but it is not an ideal short, the real wire has resistance.

Comment: Capacitors have limits on pulse current withstanding. You may not always find the information you want to find on this topic, but sometimes the capacitor datasheet or an app note will have it available. Also, shorting larger capacitors can give rise to higher energy sparks which may eject hot metal fragments. This can also damage contacts on mechanical switches (including relays).

Comment: 1000 uF would be considered a large capacitor. But the voltage also matters. 1000 uF charged up to 1V may not be too bad. 1000uF charged up to 50V will put out a very big spark.

Comment: The most common way to discharge a capacitor is seen in nature when lightning strikes occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's potentially unsafe. the high discharge current could damage the switch or even the capacitor.

1000uF charged to 12V is enough to make sparks and to weld fine wires.